# Very slow MySQL COUNT DISTINCT query, even with indexes — how can this be optimised?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, aggregate-functions

I have a MySQL (MariaDB 10.3) query, which takes almost 60 seconds to run. I need to optimise this significantly, as it's frustrating users of my web app.

The query returns the name of a user then 12 columns showing how many customers they signed up, by month, who are eligible to earn commission. It then returns a further 12 columns showing how many commission entries were recorded for the user within each month. (The query needs to return in this 24-column format for compatibility reasons.)

Here's the query:

```sql
SELECT
    people.full_name AS "Name",

    /* Count how many unique customers are eligible for commission in each month, for a rolling 12-month window */
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN customers.commission_start_date BETWEEN "2020-08-01" AND "2020-08-31" THEN customers.id END)) AS "eligible_customers_month_1",
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN customers.commission_start_date BETWEEN "2020-09-01" AND "2020-09-30" THEN customers.id END)) AS "eligible_customers_month_2",
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN customers.commission_start_date BETWEEN "2020-10-01" AND "2020-10-31" THEN customers.id END)) AS "eligible_customers_month_3",
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN customers.commission_start_date BETWEEN "2020-11-01" AND "2020-11-30" THEN customers.id END)) AS "eligible_customers_month_4",
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN customers.commission_start_date BETWEEN "2020-12-01" AND "2020-12-31" THEN customers.id END)) AS "eligible_customers_month_5",
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN customers.commission_start_date BETWEEN "2021-01-01" AND "2021-01-31" THEN customers.id END)) AS "eligible_customers_month_6",
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN customers.commission_start_date BETWEEN "2021-02-01" AND "2021-02-28" THEN customers.id END)) AS "eligible_customers_month_7",
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN customers.commission_start_date BETWEEN "2021-03-01" AND "2021-03-31" THEN customers.id END)) AS "eligible_customers_month_8",
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN customers.commission_start_date BETWEEN "2021-04-01" AND "2021-04-30" THEN customers.id END)) AS "eligible_customers_month_9",
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN customers.commission_start_date BETWEEN "2021-05-01" AND "2021-05-31" THEN customers.id END)) AS "eligible_customers_month_10",
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN customers.commission_start_date BETWEEN "2021-06-01" AND "2021-06-30" THEN customers.id END)) AS "eligible_customers_month_11",
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN customers.commission_start_date BETWEEN "2021-07-01" AND "2021-07-31" THEN customers.id END)) AS "eligible_customers_month_12",

    /* In each month of a rolling 12-month window, count how many unique commission entries were recorded. */
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN user_commission.commission_paid_at BETWEEN "2020-08-01" AND "2020-08-31" THEN user_commission.id END)) AS "total_sales_1",
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN user_commission.commission_paid_at BETWEEN "2020-09-01" AND "2020-09-30" THEN user_commission.id END)) AS "total_sales_2",
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN user_commission.commission_paid_at BETWEEN "2020-10-01" AND "2020-10-31" THEN user_commission.id END)) AS "total_sales_3",
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN user_commission.commission_paid_at BETWEEN "2020-11-01" AND "2020-11-30" THEN user_commission.id END)) AS "total_sales_4",
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN user_commission.commission_paid_at BETWEEN "2020-12-01" AND "2020-12-31" THEN user_commission.id END)) AS "total_sales_5",
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN user_commission.commission_paid_at BETWEEN "2021-01-01" AND "2021-01-31" THEN user_commission.id END)) AS "total_sales_6",
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN user_commission.commission_paid_at BETWEEN "2021-02-01" AND "2021-02-28" THEN user_commission.id END)) AS "total_sales_7",
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN user_commission.commission_paid_at BETWEEN "2021-03-01" AND "2021-03-31" THEN user_commission.id END)) AS "total_sales_8",
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN user_commission.commission_paid_at BETWEEN "2021-04-01" AND "2021-04-30" THEN user_commission.id END)) AS "total_sales_9",
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN user_commission.commission_paid_at BETWEEN "2021-05-01" AND "2021-05-31" THEN user_commission.id END)) AS "total_sales_10",
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN user_commission.commission_paid_at BETWEEN "2021-06-01" AND "2021-06-30" THEN user_commission.id END)) AS "total_sales_11",
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN user_commission.commission_paid_at BETWEEN "2021-07-01" AND "2021-07-31" THEN user_commission.id END)) AS "total_sales_12"

FROM users

LEFT JOIN people ON people.id = users.person_id
LEFT JOIN customers ON customers.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN user_commission ON user_commission.user_id = users.id

WHERE users.id NOT IN (103, 2, 155, 24, 137, 141, 143, 149, 152, 3, 135)

GROUP BY users.id
```

And here's the output from `EXPLAIN SELECT`:

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | users | index | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 |  | 16 | Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | people | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | users.person_id | 1 | Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | customers | ref | user_id | user_id | 5 | users.id | 284 | Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | user_commission | ref | comm_index,user_id | comm_index | 4 | users.id | 465 | Using index |

`comm_index` is a `UNIQUE` index on the `user_commission` table, covering `user_id,order_id,commission_paid_at`.

I'm a bit stumped as to what to do next — there are indexes in place, and not many rows for the engine to parse per table.

Any clues would be much appreciated — thanks!

Comment: [Edit] the question and add the `CREATE` statements of the tables and indexes involved too.

Comment: how many rows is not many?  how fast are queries just joining customers and just returning the customer columns and just joining commissions and returning just the commissions columns?  if those separately are much faster, do them in two subqueries and join the two of them (and people) on user id

Comment: This is a reporting query, not suitable for highly interactive app. You can run the query only once every hour and cache the result. I fail to see why you want to run it for every user, every time.

Answer (score 1):

Lets first start that this query going for EVERY user (with the few exceptions you want to EXCLUDE -- I did not include that exclusion list in my query ), I would ask why are you trying to show sales and commission counts for all users to see how all users are doing.  I would think that if I was a rep for your company, I only care about how MY activities are going.

Next, this might be a good instance to suggest a pre-aggregation table of the counts per month per user so you dont have to keep re-trying to compute on the fly.  If the data does not change such as when a new customer is signed-up, or a sales commission is entered, you may be best to keep those computed at the end of every day for the given user/month/year it represents.  But that too is an alternative.

Now, the WHY you are probably getting hit with large delay times, and you are using COUNT( DISTINCT ) on the given customer and commission tables is you are getting a Cartesian result.  So, lets go with a scenario you have 100 users.  Of those users, in a given month, one user has 3 new customers, 2 commissions because they are new.  Yet a long-term rep has 37 new customers and 45 commissions.  THESE are the ones killing you.  Because your left-join is on user ID, it is taking 1 record from the customers table for a given user and joining that to the commission table for the same user id the sale recorded against..  So the first rep it creates 6 entries to count against (3 * 2).  But the second user goes through 1,665 iterations.  So, this  Cartesian (or cross-join) result is killing you.

So that is the WHY its failing.  Now, on to the solution I have for you.  You appear to have a bunch of hard-coded dates left-and-right through the code.  What happens when next month comes.  Do you have to hard-code fix the begin/end dates?  If so, then the solution I have for you will simplify that all.

By using the "WITH" (Common-Table-Expression  aka CTE), you can pre-write queries and use those "aliase" names AS-IF you wrote each of the queries within a multi-nested query.  But the benefit is the query is written once, even if you keep re-using the alias name reference.

So here is the query and I'll describe / break it down next so you can view/follow along.

```
with Rolling12 as
(
select
        @rptMonth := @rptMonth +1 as QryMonth,
        @beginDate as AtLeastDate,
        date_add( @beginDate, interval 1 month ) as AndLessThanDate,
        @beginDate := date_add( @beginDate, interval 1 month )
    from 
        user_commission
            JOIN ( select @rptMonth := 0, 
                          @beginDate := date_sub( 
                                            date_add(   
                                                date_sub( curdate(), 
                                                interval day( curdate()) -1 day ), 
                                            interval 1 month ), 
                                        interval 1 year )
                ) sqlvars
    limit 12
),
MinMaxDates as
(
    select 
            min( AtLeastDate ) MinDate,
            max( AndLessThanDate ) MaxDate
        from
            Rolling12
),
SumCommission as
(
select 
        uc.user_id,
        coalesce( sum( CASE WHEN R12.QryMonth = 1 then 1 else 0 end ), 0) commission01,
        coalesce( sum( CASE WHEN R12.QryMonth = 2 then 1 else 0 end ), 0) commission02,
        coalesce( sum( CASE WHEN R12.QryMonth = 3 then 1 else 0 end ), 0) commission03,
        coalesce( sum( CASE WHEN R12.QryMonth = 4 then 1 else 0 end ), 0) commission04,
        coalesce( sum( CASE WHEN R12.QryMonth = 5 then 1 else 0 end ), 0) commission05,
        coalesce( sum( CASE WHEN R12.QryMonth = 6 then 1 else 0 end ), 0) commission06,
        coalesce( sum( CASE WHEN R12.QryMonth = 7 then 1 else 0 end ), 0) commission07,
        coalesce( sum( CASE WHEN R12.QryMonth = 8 then 1 else 0 end ), 0) commission08,
        coalesce( sum( CASE WHEN R12.QryMonth = 9 then 1 else 0 end ), 0) commission09,
        coalesce( sum( CASE WHEN R12.QryMonth = 10 then 1 else 0 end ), 0) commission10,
        coalesce( sum( CASE WHEN R12.QryMonth = 11 then 1 else 0 end ), 0) commission11,
        coalesce( sum( CASE WHEN R12.QryMonth = 12 then 1 else 0 end ), 0) commission12
    from 
        user_commission uc
            JOIN Rolling12 R12
                on uc.commission_paid_at >= R12.AtLeastDate
                AND uc.commission_paid_at < R12.AndLessThanDate
            -- only a single row returned for MinMaxDates source
            JOIN MinMaxDates mm
    where
            uc.commission_paid_at >= mm.MinDate
        AND uc.commission_paid_at < mm.MaxDate
    group by
        uc.user_id
),
SumCustomers as
(
select 
        c.user_id,
        coalesce( sum( CASE WHEN R12.QryMonth = 1 then 1 else 0 end ), 0) customers01,
        coalesce( sum( CASE WHEN R12.QryMonth = 2 then 1 else 0 end ), 0) customers02,
        coalesce( sum( CASE WHEN R12.QryMonth = 3 then 1 else 0 end ), 0) customers03,
        coalesce( sum( CASE WHEN R12.QryMonth = 4 then 1 else 0 end ), 0) customers04,
        coalesce( sum( CASE WHEN R12.QryMonth = 5 then 1 else 0 end ), 0) customers05,
        coalesce( sum( CASE WHEN R12.QryMonth = 6 then 1 else 0 end ), 0) customers06,
        coalesce( sum( CASE WHEN R12.QryMonth = 7 then 1 else 0 end ), 0) customers07,
        coalesce( sum( CASE WHEN R12.QryMonth = 8 then 1 else 0 end ), 0) customers08,
        coalesce( sum( CASE WHEN R12.QryMonth = 9 then 1 else 0 end ), 0) customers09,
        coalesce( sum( CASE WHEN R12.QryMonth = 10 then 1 else 0 end ), 0) customers10,
        coalesce( sum( CASE WHEN R12.QryMonth = 11 then 1 else 0 end ), 0) customers11,
        coalesce( sum( CASE WHEN R12.QryMonth = 12 then 1 else 0 end ), 0) customers12
    from 
        customers c
            JOIN Rolling12 R12
                on c.commission_start_date  >= R12.AtLeastDate
                AND c.commission_start_date  < R12.AndLessThanDate
            -- only a single row returned for MinMaxDates source
            JOIN MinMaxDates mm
    where
            c.commission_start_date  >= mm.MinDate
        AND c.commission_start_date  < mm.MaxDate
    group by
        c.user_id
)

select 
        u.id,
        p.full_name AS "Name",
        com.Commission01,
        com.Commission02,
        com.Commission03,
        com.Commission04,
        com.Commission05,
        com.Commission06,
        com.Commission07,
        com.Commission08,
        com.Commission09,
        com.Commission10,
        com.Commission11,
        com.Commission12,
        cst.Customers01,
        cst.Customers02,
        cst.Customers03,
        cst.Customers04,
        cst.Customers05,
        cst.Customers06,
        cst.Customers07,
        cst.Customers08,
        cst.Customers09,
        cst.Customers10,
        cst.Customers11,
        cst.Customers12
    from 
        users u
            JOIN People p
                ON u.person_id = p.id
            LEFT JOIN SumCommission com
                on u.id = com.user_id
            LEFT JOIN SumCustomers cst
                on u.id = cst.user_id;
```

You state that you are running on a rolling 12-month period.  For this, I have my first CTE alias "Rolling12".  This query is a setup for the rest of the query.  It creates MySQL variables and keeps computing an updated begin/end date for each month represented.  It starts by taking the current date ex: July 6 and rolls it back to July 1.  Then adds 1 month to get August 1, then subtracts 1 year from that Aug 1, 2020 for the beginning period of your 12-month rolling computation.  I then simple join to the commission table and limit to 12 records, each time going forward and making a column for the beginning and ending dates of the pay periods and just assigning a month ID sequence to it.

If you highlight and just run the query inside the With Rolling12 as ( the query ), you will see what it builds out.  This prevents all the hard-coding dates associated with your current 24 case/count distinct when conditions.

Then a comma and the next CTE for MinMaxDates.  Here, I am querying from this 12-month roll to get the minimum begin and end date for the entire period you are reporting, so when querying the sales customers and commissions, I can join to this as a single row result for the begin/end dates of details.

Next are the SumCommission and SumCustomers.  These are joining against the CTE "Rolling12" records with the JOIN so we can associate the specific commission or customer to that one date range entry.  So from that, I get the query month of the rolling 12 and sum() it.  But since sum() of a null results in null, I wrap it with coalesce( calculation, 0 ) to show 0 as a worst-case.

The reason for each of these being run individually and grouped by user is to prevent the Cartesian result previously mentioned.

Once those individual parts are all done, I now start with the user, join to people to get the name, then LEFT-JOIN to the respective other SUM() queries.  So, if a user had only a new customer for a month, but no commission, you would only have a record in that set and not the other, thus preventing the duplication of query results requiring your DISTINCT to begin with.

So, even though it looks long and may be confusing, especially the WITH CTE context, look at it to its individual parts.  The SUMs() are pre-grouped by user ID, so each sum() result will only have one possible record per user for that given period.

As for indexes to help optimize the query, I would ensure the commission and customer table have an index on ( dateField, useridField ) respectively.

I would be interested in knowing how well this performs when you give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you select about all rows instead of only the months you are interested in.

- Solution: A `WHERE` clause to restrict the rows taken into consideration.

Then you cross join a user's customers with the user's commissions, thus building a huge intermediate result you don't need and want.

- Solution: Aggregate before joining.

In order to

This can look thus for instance:

```
SELECT
    people.full_name AS "Name",

    cu.eligible_customers_month_1,
    cu.eligible_customers_month_2,
    ...

    co.total_sales_1,
    co.total_sales_2,
    ...
FROM users
LEFT JOIN people ON people.id = users.person_id
LEFT JOIN
(
  select 
    user_id,
    max(case when month_index = 1 then cnt else 0 end) as eligible_customers_month_1,
    max(case when month_index = 2 then cnt else 0 end) as eligible_customers_month_2,
    ...
  from
  (
    select
      user_id,
      (year(current_date) * 12 + month(current_date))
        - (year(commission_start_date) * 12 + month(commission_start_date))
        + 1 as month_index,
      count(*) as cnt
    from customers
    where commission_start_date >=
          last_day(current_date) + interval 1 day - interval 1 year
    group by user_id, month_num
  ) months
  group by user_id
) cu ON cu.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN
(
(
  select 
    user_id,
    max(case when month_index = 1 then cnt else 0 end) as total_sales_1,
    max(case when month_index = 2 then cnt else 0 end) as total_sales_2,
    ...
  from
    select 
      user_id,
      (year(current_date) * 12 + month(current_date))
        - (year(commission_paid_at) * 12 + month(commission_paid_at))
        + 1 as month_index,
      count(*) as cnt
    from user_commission
    where commission_paid_at >=
          last_day(current_date) + interval 1 day - interval 1 year
    group by user_id, month_num
  ) months
  group by user_id
) co ON co.user_id = users.id
WHERE users.id NOT IN (103, 2, 155, 24, 137, 141, 143, 149, 152, 3, 135)
ORDER BY users.id;
```

Recommended indexes:

```
create index idx1 on customers (commission_start_date, user_id);
create index idx2 on user_commission (commission_paid_at, user_id);
```